# Contour Integrals using Legs

Tags: complex-analysis

> For function $f$ and contours $C$ use parametric representations of $C$, or legs of $C$ to evaluate

$$\int_{C}f(z)dz$$$$f(z)=\pi e^{\pi \bar z}, \bar z=x-iy$$

> where $C$ is the boundary of the square with vertices at the points $0,1,1+i,$ and $i$, the orientation of $C$ being in the counterclockwise direction. *Answer* $4(e^\pi-1)$:

$$z=x+i, y=1$$$$I_1=\int_{1}^{0}\pi e^{\pi x}e^{-i\pi y}dx$$$$I_1=\frac{-\pi}{\pi}e^{\pi x}\big |_1^0= e^\pi-1$$$$z=iy, x=0$$$$I_2=\int_{1}^{0}\pi e^{-i\pi y}idy=\frac{i\pi}{-i\pi}e^{-\pi i y}=-e^{-\pi i y}\big |_1^0=-2$$$$z=1-iy, dz=-idy, I_3=\pi\int_{1}^{0}e^{\pi{(1-iy)}}(-i)dy=-i\pi\int_{1}^{0}e^\pi e^{-i\pi y}dy=2e^\pi$$ $$y=0,z=x, dz=dx, I_4=\pi\int_{0}^{1}e^{\pi x}dx=\frac{\pi}{\pi}(e^\pi-1)=e^\pi-1$$
$$I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4=4(e^\pi-1)$$

> But where to from here? {nearly there!}

Comment: How do you parametrize the path $C$.?

Comment: The $4$ integrals are given by
$\left\{\,\mathrm{e}^{\pi } - 1,-2\,\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{e}^{\pi },-\,\mathrm{e}^{\pi } \left(\,\mathrm{e}^{\pi } - 1\right),2\,\mathrm{i}\right\}$: From $\texttt{Mathematica}$.